# Need a little guidance for latex document design

Tags: book-design, documentclass-writing

I want to use LaTEX to write a fascicle (a small book part of a bigger set of books). So I need some specialized design. For example a specialized design for headers, specialized edging, rearranged margins etc. So my questions are:

Which document class should I prefer? Or should I start my own one? If I should start my own, could you recommend a tutorial/document for this job?

If I use an already-existing document class, which macros should I change and how should I change them?

Comment: While I am not clear what a fascicle is exactly, but by the description of you requirements I would suggest you look at the Memoir class.  The manual is here and I suggest you look at the table of contents. http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/memoir/memman.pdf

Comment: What is a fascicle? What have you tried? What exactly are you having trouble with? Q1) Hard to say without more information. Q2) Probably not. Q3) Probably inapplicable. Q4) Probably much too broad a question to be addressed in a (single) question here, though it is hard to say for sure without more details.

Comment: @cfr: I just looked after it: A fascicle seems to be some kind of a pack of ancient/medieval scriptures, e.g as used in monasterys etc.

Comment: @cfr In my mother tongue it's used for a little published book which is part of a bigger set of books. For example "Integral Fascicle" (which is part of Calculus book.). To be sure I looked for word meaning. The first definition of  fascicle is what I want, so I used that word. It doesn't matter what fascicle exactly is. The question is basically "To make a special design in LaTeX, what should I do?". If you could suggest me a tutorial, documentation that's enough for me.

Comment: What is your mother tongue? `fascicle` sounds Italian?

Comment: My mother tongue is Turkish. In Turkish it is written `fasikül`, a French loan word with Latin origin. In English the word `fascicle` comes from the same Latin word. That word is common in my language. I am surprised that it's used that much rare in English.

Comment: There is no general answer to the question "To make a special design in LaTeX, what should I do?" other than "Search for existing solutions or, failing that, solutions to similar problems which you can modify appropriately." Of course, one can always say "design a custom class from scratch" but that is a large undertaking and not for the faint of heart, inexperienced or rushed. Moreover, it is always better to search first since it is a waste of time to duplicate existing efforts without cause. So, if that's your question, the answer is "search". Start with CTAN.

Comment: @jnbrq Perhaps a better translation would be ªbooklet” (small book).

Comment: @egreg Yes, I have also considered it. But it may also represent something  which is used for advertisement purposes. Fascicle as it's defined in dictionary.com represents a small published part of a book, something more serious. For example "Integral Fascicle" part of "Calculus Book". But if it's confusing very much I can change the question.

Comment: Given that this is a site on TeX, it is interesting that the first time I encountered the word "fascicle" was on Knuth's "Recent News" page, where he uses it for parts of forthcoming volumes of TAOCP that he is releasing for public preview.

Comment: Many (well, how many is many?) projects publish in fascicles. It is common in dictionary projects (TLL, TLG, OLD, OED, etc.) where you might publish a fascicle for the letter A while working on the rest of the alphabet -- eventually all the fascicles will be published together in a single (collection of) volume(s).  The issue is that you want a consistent style across all fascicles. For that either a set of common `.sty` files and/or a custom `.cls` would be approriate. I'd still use as a base a feature-rich class such as `memoir` or `KOMA-Script`.

Comment: What you need to think about is what elements must be the same across fascicles: headers/footers, chapter and section styling, custom environments, style of indices and 'tables of <X>', bibliography stuff.  Make a list; spend time thinking about all of these things; and design in such a way that changing it will not become too manual-labour intensive (i.e., you want to design so the changes occur at the class or style file level, and not need to be sorted out in the 'body' of the `.tex` files). And, no matter how much you plan, *you will need to make changes as you go*.

Comment: The most important advice for cross-volume consistency: make extensive but judicious use of macros.  This will make your life much easier, especially when it comes to indexing, which comes late in the production cycle but can be a real pain in the ass if you didn't design with the requirements of indexing in mind from the start.

Comment: @jon It's very nice to see someone who is familiar with fascicles. Thank you for your guidence.

Comment: @jon If you can elaborate your comment and answer that would be great. I wish that your answer contains more examples on **modifying classes** such as `memoir` class file, or at least contains references to a good tutorial (not the `memoir`'s user's manual.).

Comment: I can write up an answer, but it cannot include a comprehensive tutorial on how to modify `memoir`: that would be beyond the scope of the nature of this site. I'll try to give some basic idea about how to do it, but, if you're new to LaTeX, I don't think this is the way to go. I'd rather opt for a series of custom `.sty` files to get started. As you become more proficient, and as the project advances, you can consider which elments should/must/could be moved into a custom class.

Comment: @jon I am not much familiar with `memoir` class. If you can give links to that kind of tutorials, that would be great. And if you can share a series of custom `.sty` files, that would be more great!